# How do I restore Grub after Windows has deleted it

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

So I had a dual boot, with Windows, and Ubuntu, but I had to re-install windows for various reasons...

Now that I have re-installed windows, windows wrote over grub, which I knew was going to happen, but I didn't think about how to fix the problem, or if it was even possible... so here is my question, how do I restore grub to allow me to boot into windows and my already installed ubuntu?

Comment: Technically windows didn't write over grub, it's still there, you just have to tell bios to use the linux partition instead of the windows partition. Also, while not technically an answer you're looking for, there's a tool you can use to specify different operating systems to be in the windows boot menu called EasyBCD - http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Comment: Can you post the results of [bootscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) pls.So that i can help you..

Answer (score 5):

There is [quite a comprehensive guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD) on the Ubuntu wiki that should work for you. I suggest giving that a go.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have installed win 7 after isntalling ubuntu in that case boot from the live cd download [Grub Customizer Portable](http://portablelinuxapps.org/Grub%20Customizer%202.1/download) and then right click properties -> permissions and tick allow excecuting and then run it by double-clicking it and then go to File -> Install to MBR.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common thing... google solves it for you! :)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708 or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file in your favorite text editor. I’m using gedit:
so press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste

```
gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Now find the section that looks like this:

```
##hiddenmenu
#Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
hiddenmenu
```

Put a `#` before `hiddenmenu` to comment that line out:

```
## hiddenmenu
# Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
#hiddenmenu
```

Let me know, if this the solution.

Regards,