# where is my grub loader

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restore Grub after Windows has deleted it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18566/how-do-i-restore-grub-after-windows-has-deleted-it)

i have recently installed ubuntu 10.10 desktop on my samsung n210 netbook from a usb. everything installed fine but now the grub menu doesn't appear and it boots straight onto windows 7 with no grub menu for a ubuntu option